# I'm in while loop looking for commands that report to same variable. Variable doesn't change when recalled

Tags: python, function, variables, while-loop

I think the title was enough to have a basic understanding of what I meant. I'll try to summarize the code as much as possible to give an idea of what I mean.

```
user_input = list(input(""))
running = True
help = ["h", "e", "l", "p"]
test = ["t", "e", "s", "t"]

def help_function():
   [...]
   user_input = list(input(""))
   return user_input

def test_function():
   [...]
   user_input = list(input(""))
   return user_input

while running:
   if user_input == help:
      help_function()
   elif user_input == test:
      test_function()
```

What I wish, is for every function to give a different input from the user, so that I can choose which function I should show them next. The problem is that as things stand now, the app just remembers the first input the user gives, I don't know how to change that. (Yes, I need inputs to be in lists, it is for a different part of the app)
I'm a beginner, I think my code shows that, thanks already for your help!

Comment: It seems like your functions are returning the `user_input`, but you are not setting `user_input` to their return.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do, but if this has to do with running a program and receiving inputs from an user, you might want to look into [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) python lib.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `user_input` is not being updated during your `while` loop. The example below updates an arbitrary `var` variable.

```py
var = "foo"

run = True
while run:
    print(var)
    var = input("New value for var: ") # your code is not updating `user_input`
    if var.lower() == "stop": # stop `while` loop
        run = False
```